# OperationalError no such column

Tags: django, model

I have tried `py manage.py makemigrations` and then `py manage.py migrate`  but when I add a new field to my model, this error occurs. I also have tried deleting all the migrations and doing the makemigrations and migrate things again but it still does not solve the problem.

Basically I have a model `Schedule` and I added a `Customer` field in it which the relationship is `customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)`

Here is my model:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    deadline_date = models.DateField()
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

Here is the migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0007_customer'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Schedule',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=250)),
                ('deadline_date', models.DateField()),
                ('deadline_time', models.TimeField()),
                ('is_completed', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('description', models.CharField(default='', max_length=1000)),
                ('responsible_department', models.CharField(choices=[('Inventory', 'Inventory'), ('Sales', 'Sales'), ('Procurement', 'Procurement'), ('Accounting', 'Accounting'), ('Technical', 'Technical'), ('Admin', 'Admin')], default='Sales', max_length=30)),
                ('customer', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='core.Customer')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  328.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such column: schedule_schedule.customer_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  551.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  224.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1662.             selection_note=_('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  232.         self._fetch_all()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  1118.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in __iter__
  53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  894.             raise original_exception

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  884.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.4-py3.6.egg\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  328.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/schedule/schedule/
Exception Value: no such column: schedule_schedule.customer_id
```

Comment: Do you have any errors when trying to migrate? Have you tried migrating with `--fake-initial`?

Comment: Can we see your entire model ?

Comment: @souldeux I have no errors when migrating. It still produces the error even with --fake

Answer (score 2):

If you deleted all the migrations and re-ran `makemigrations`, then your migrations and your database will be out of sync.

Your easiest fix is to drop the database and run `migrate` again. If you've got important data and can't drop the database, then getting the database and migrations back in sync could be tricky. You'll need to create the `customer_id` column manually, and possibly make other changes as well.

Comment: sorry sir, but how do you drop the database?

Comment: That depends on which database engine you are using. If you are using sqlite, you simply remove the `db.sqlite3` file.

Comment: i dropped my database and migrated again but it still hasn't solved the problem

Comment: Please edit your question and add the migration files for the `schedule` app.

Comment: I added the migration files, sir

Comment: Please show the full error after dropping the database. The migration includes the `customer` field, so you shouldn't get *no such column: schedule_schedule.customer_id*.

Comment: Ok I already solved the problem. My customer field had a field I named 'email'. I changed it to email_address and did the migrations then everything had worked fine. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You named it twice.

```
customer = ...(Customer)
```

Django can't distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I opened my sqlite database and I manually added that field. This solved the problem for me.